# Sending all lan traffic to monitor PC

Tags: windows, wireshark, dd-wrt

I setup a Windows Server 2022 PC to monitor all LAN traffic. I have the computer connected by Ethernet to the monitor PC and have this as a `Firewall` script for my DD-wrt router:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ROUTE --tee --gw 192.168.1.254

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ROUTE --tee --gw 192.168.1.254
```

When I wireshark the ethernet adapter I don't see any mirrored traffic. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible problems in your set-up.

---

### 1. Does your dd-wrt even get to see the traffic you're interested in?

Your dd-wrt is probably actually a combination of a small switch and a router. If the switch component has been implemented as a simple unmanaged switch, any traffic between any two local systems may be handled solely by the switch component, and the router component won't see it at all. In this case, the only way to get the traffic to the router component would be to perform a MAC table attack against the switch component.

If you have this problem, then you might need a managed switch that includes port mirroring functionality.

---

### 2. You are trying to use an obsolete iptables add-on.

Neither [generic `iptables` documentation](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) nor [dd-wrt specific documentation](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Iptables_command#Targets) mention an iptables target named `ROUTE`.

And even if it existed, you are trying to invoke the `ROUTE` target in a `POSTROUTING` filter chain? I believe at that point in the iptables processing as it currently exists, "that ship has already sailed": there is no way back to the routing decision step from the POSTROUTING step. ([simple diagram](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/laymans-iptables-101/), [more detailed diagram](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/IP_Tables#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)) The duplicate packet would have to go out the same interface as the original is going to, which might not be the right one.

[This answer at Server Fault.SE](https://serverfault.com/a/267149/442837) suggests a syntax like yours, but note that the answer was written in 2011 and refers to a blog from 2008, which seems to be no longer accessible. The other link refers to patch-o-matic: [an obsolete system for iptables add-ons](https://netfilter.org/projects/patch-o-matic/index.html) which were too new/untested to go into the main kernel source. As patch-o-matic was replaced first by the patch-o-matic NG and then by the current [xtables-addons](https://inai.de/projects/xtables-addons/), the `ROUTE` target was apparently dropped somewhere along the way.

Even if you were running a >10 years old version of dd-wrt, it might or might not have the patch-o-matic add-ons included. Have you used `iptables -L -vn -t mangle` to to confirm that your script commands have actually been accepted and taken effect?

The modern equivalent would use the `TEE` target from `iptables-extensions`, and out of abundance of caution, I would add a condition to stop it from duplicating any packets that are already going to the monitor host:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d \! 192.168.1.254 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.254
```

The above command should cover all incoming traffic to this host, but for locally-generated outgoing traffic, you would need another line:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d \! 192.168.1.254 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Since the cloning happens in the PREROUTING step (as given in the documentation example; I'm not sure if it could be done in the POSTROUTING step, as the documentation of the `TEE` extension is minimal)

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested any of this.